# In pybind11, how do you make a py::module known for import?

Tags: pybind11

In an embedded C++ program in pybind11, I'm defining a python module to use as a container for multiple python objects that I don't want to expose to the global namespace. I then want import this module as needed. But it appears that just defining a module through `py::module('mymodule')` isn't enough.

The following sample code compiles without problems but terminates with the run time error "No module named 'application'". So how do I make the "application" module known to python?

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    // Construct python wrappers for them
    py::module m("application");

    // Define some objects in the module
    m.add_object("pet", py::cast("dog"));

    // Import the module and access its objects
    py::exec("import application\n"
             "print(application.pet)");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pybind defines `PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE` macro to create embedded modules.

https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/embedding.html#adding-embedded-modules

```
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_EMBEDDED_MODULE(fast_calc, m) {
    // `m` is a `py::module` which is used to bind functions and classes
    m.def("add", [](int i, int j) {
        return i + j;
    });
}

int main() {
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};

    auto fast_calc = py::module::import("fast_calc");
    auto result = fast_calc.attr("add")(1, 2).cast<int>();
    assert(result == 3);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as I was explicitly asking for how to make the `py::module m` eligible for import. Not how to create a module another way.

Comment: I gave the answer based on what you asked. True, I might get it wrong. You may want to update question make it clear (not only for me, but for others to get better answers). Do you really need to create module *dynamically* ? Why static method with macro would not work for you? Either way I think it's possible to do with python c api, but I doubt that it's exposed by pybind11.